# Objective-c convert NSString into NSInteger

Tags: objective-c, string, integer

I've got this little problem. When I have a string "3 568 030" and I use [myString intValue]; it gives me result just 3, the problem is I want to convert the whole number into int/nsinteger. The string always contains just the number if that's any help. I tried using replaceoccurencesofstring (or what is the name) and it somehow didn't work...
Thanks

Comment: So you replaced the spaces with nothing in the number already?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Do:

```
NSString *str = @"3 568 030";

int aValue = [[str stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@" " withString:@""] intValue];
NSLog(@"%d", aValue);
```

output

3568030

Answer (score 8):

That is because of the spaces on your string you will have to remove the whitespaces first like this:

```
NSString *trimmedString = [myString stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@" " withString:@""];

NSInteger *value = [trimmedString intValue];
```

Comment: Trimming doesn't remove characters from the middle of the string

Answer (score 2):

My guess is that you're using `stringByReplacingOccurencesOfString::` wrongly.

```
//Remove spaces.
myString = [myString stringByReplacingOccurencesOfString:@" " withString @""];
int myNumber = [myString intValue];
```

Answer (score 2):

First, remove all the whitespaces in your original string using :

```
NSString *trimmedString = [yourOriginalString stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:
                              [NSCharacterSet whitespaceAndNewlineCharacterSet]];
```

Then, you can convert it to an int/NSInteger. beware: using `[myString intValue]` will cast your string to an int, but `[myString integerValue]` will cast it to a NSInteger.

Answer (score 1):

```
NSNumberFormatter * f = [[NSNumberFormatter alloc] init];
[f setNumberStyle:NSNumberFormatterDecimalStyle];
NSNumber * myNumber = [f numberFromString:@"42"];
[f release];
```